# Define a new addition and multiplication and check the equality

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set $V$ = {$(x,y): x,y \in \mathbb{R}$}.

Define a new addition and multiplication on $V$ by $(x,y) + (a,b) = (x+a-2,y+b)$ and $k(x,y) = (kx-2k-2x+6,ky)$.

Check whether the following equality holds for all $u,v \in V$ and all $k \in \mathbb{R}$: 
$$k(u+v)=ku+kv$$

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Well that's what I was trying to understand. I dont know what this question is really asking. But I think I am supposed to check the equality using the new addition and multiplication definitions provided.

Comment: @KJay: You're right, you need to check whether this equality is true or not. Was that your question or do you not know how to proceed?

Comment: Yes, I don't know where to start with this @Diglett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would like to check if the equation
$$
k(u+v) = ku + kv
$$
is true for all $u,v \in V$ and all $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Let me give you a blueprint for the solution of this problem**:

Let $k$ be an arbitrary real number and $u,v$ be arbitrary elements in $V$.

1. Since $u,v \in V$, there are real numbers $a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
   $$
   u = (x,y) \quad \text{and} \quad v =(a,b).
   $$
2. Compute $u+v$ by using your newly defined addition.
3. Compute $k(u+v)$ by using your newly defined multiplication.
4. Compute $ku$ and $kv$ by using your newly defined multiplication.
5. Compute $ku + kv$ by using your newly defined addition.
6. Compare your results from 3. and 5. by comparing the entries of the vectors. This shows whether your equality is true or not.

   - If the equality seems to be not true, try to find explicit $a,b,x,y$, so that the equality does not hold.

If you need further help, then you can let me know and I try to give you more hints.